# How to decide a convex function of some variables is also convex for another set of variables

Tags: multivariable-calculus, functions, convex-analysis, vector-analysis

I have a multivariate gaussian function with a given set of variables. I have another set of variables where all of the variables of multivariate gaussian function are convex functions for this set. I am wondering that is the gaussian function also convex for this second set or is there a way that I can investigate the convexity?

Comment: Could you please be a bit more specific and use notation? Also, it is curious to me that a Gaussian would be convex... They are usually bell-shaped and hence nonconvex.

Comment: I have a set of three variables X = {x1,x2,x3} and a Gauss distribution with a given mean and covariance function. These three variables are related with another set of variables such that x1 = (y1-y2)^2+(y3-y4)^2, x2 = (y1-y2)^2+(y5-y6)^2 and x3 = (y3-y4)^2+(y5-y6)^2, where Y ={y1,y2,y3,y4,y5,y6}. Actually, you are right that I am wrong about the convexity topic, but what I want to do is optimizing for the maximum likelihood of gauss function for the Y set of variables. Is that a reasonable optimization problem? Is the distribution still a Gaussian for these new variables?

Comment: Yeah probably, try looking in the literature for "maximum likelihood estimates" -- after some logarithms and negation, these problems sometimes manifest as easily tractable convex minimization problems :)